# Distributed timer service

Tags: quartz-scheduler, distributed-computing, distributed

I am looking for a distributed timer service. Multiple remote client services should be able to register for callbacks (via REST apis) after specified intervals. The length of an interval can be 1 minute. I can live with an error margin of around 1 minute. The number of such callbacks can go up to 100,000 for now but I would need to scale up later. I have been looking at schedulers like `Quartz` but I am not sure if they are a fit for the problem. With `Quartz`, I will probably have to save the callback requests in a DB and poll every minute for overdue requests on 100,000 rows. I am not sure that will scale. Are there any out of the box solutions around? Else, how do I go about building one?

Answer (score 0):

*Posting as answer since i cant comment*

One more options to consider is a message queue. Where you publish a message with scheduled delay so that consumers can consume after that delay.

[Amazon SQS Delay Queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html)

> Delay queues let you postpone the delivery of new messages in a queue for the specified number of seconds. If you create a delay queue, any message that you send to that queue is invisible to consumers for the duration of the delay period. You can use the CreateQueue action to create a delay queue by setting the DelaySeconds attribute to any value between 0 and 900 (15 minutes). You can also change an existing queue into a delay queue using the SetQueueAttributes action to set the queue's DelaySeconds attribute.

[Scheduling Messages with RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/)

> https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/
>
> A user can declare an exchange with the type x-delayed-message and then publish messages with the custom header x-delay expressing in milliseconds a delay time for the message. The message will be delivered to the respective queues after x-delay milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

## Out of the box solution

[RocketMQ](https://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/schedule-example/) meets your requirements since it supports the **Scheduled messages**:

> Scheduled messages differ from normal messages in that they won’t be
>   delivered until a provided time later.

You can register your callbacks by sending such messages:

```
Message message = new Message("TestTopic", "");
message.setDelayTimeLevel(3);
producer.send(message);
```

And then, listen to this topic to deal with your callbacks:

```
consumer.subscribe("TestTopic", "*");
consumer.registerMessageListener(new MessageListenerConcurrently() {...})
```

It does well in almost every way except that the `DelayTimeLevel` options can only be defined before RocketMQ server start, which means that if your MQ server has configuration `messageDelayLevel=1s 5s 10s`, then you just can not register your callback with `delayIntervalTime=3s`.

## DIY

`Quartz`+storage can build such callback service as you mentioned, while I don't recommend that you store callback data in relational DB since you hope it to achieve high TPS and constructing distributed service will be hard to get rid of lock and transaction which bring complexity to DB coding.

I do suggest storing callback data in Redis. Because it has better performance than relational DB and it's data structure `ZSET` suits this scene well.

I once developed a timed callback service based on Redis and Dubbo. it provides some more useful features. Maybe you can get some ideas from it  https://github.com/joooohnli/delay-callback